# Cone in spherical coordinates after rotation

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations, spherical-coordinates, convex-cone

A volume of a $3$-d cone with the apex at the origin of a Cartesian coordinate system $\mathbf{x} = [x, y, z]^T$ and with its axis of symmetry (given by a unit vector $\mathbf{e}_c$) aligned with the $z$-axis and an aperture angle of $2\alpha$ is given in the corresponding spherical coordinates by

$$
0\le r \le a \\
0 \le \theta \le 2\pi \\
0 \le \phi \le \alpha
$$

What does this definition become after we rotate the Cartesian coordinates by a matrix $\mathbf{R}$, i.e. $\mathbf{x'}$ = $\mathbf{Rx}$?

It seems to me that, in general, the new ranges of $[r', \theta', \phi']$ will become functions of other coordinates, e.g. $\phi_{Max}' = f(r',\theta')$, but how do we find these functions and the ranges? I guess we need to take projections of the cone onto the planes defined by new coordinates, but I am not clear on how exactly this is to be done and I am not sure if this will actually lead to a solution.

I thought I could start by first defining the ranges in the original $\mathbf{x}$ coordinates and then substituting the expression for $[x,y,z]$ in terms of the new $[x',y',z']$ coordinates, but if I take the equation of the cone in the original coordinates $\mathbf{x}$, which (if I am not mistaken) are given by the following implicit equations

$$
0 \le z \le a \cos{\alpha} \\
x^2 + y^2 \le z^2 \tan^2{\alpha}
$$

then I am not even able to define these as ranges for each of $[x, y, z]$. So I am stuck at the very beginning.

I am looking for an "algebraic" approach since I would need to extend this to multiple dimensions.

**Add 1**

I suppose one can also try substituting the inverse relationships between spherical and Cartesian coordinates, i.e. $ r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ etc,  into the first set of inequalities above and then substitute the expressions for $\mathbf{x}$ in terms of $\mathbf{x'}$, i.e. $x = \left( \mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{x'} \right)_{1}$, but not sure if this would actually work and I suspect that there is a simpler method.

If I try to work through it, I get to

$$
0\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \le a \\
0 \le \mathrm{arctan2}(y,x) \le 2\pi \\
0 \le  \arctan\left( \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{z} \right) \le \alpha
$$

which then needs to be split into $3$ sets for simultaneous inequalities for the different values of $x$ in  $\mathrm{arctan2}()$.

So, for $x > 0$ we have that $ -0.5\pi < \mathrm{arctan2}(y,x) < 0.5\pi$ and hence

$$
0\le x^2+y^2+z^2 \le a^2 \\
-\infty < \frac{y}{x} < + \infty \\
0 \le  \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{z} \le \tan(\alpha)
$$

which kind of leads back to the same point as before. So, no progress with this approach, it seems.

**Add 2**

The first set of inequalities in my opening post above defines a volume of a "spherical cone" (which is a conical "wedge" of a sphere); a volume of a cone is instead defined by

$$
0 \le \theta \le 2\pi \\
0 \le \phi \le \alpha \\
0\le r \le a \frac{\cos{\alpha}}{\cos{\phi}}
$$

As suggested by @Circle Lover , we can calculate an angle between the rotated axis of the cone and a radial unit vector in spherical coordinates, which means

$$
0 \le \arccos{\left( \mathbf{e}_r \cdot \mathbf{R}\mathbf{e}_c \right)} \le \alpha \\
0 \le r \le a \frac{\cos{\alpha}}{\mathbf{e}_r \cdot \mathbf{R}\mathbf{e}_c}
$$

but this is still missing one inequality to comlete the definition.

Comment: A rotation matrix is simply a translation in each of the angular coordinates, nothing complicated. And not worth going into Cartesian for, rotations are the whole purpose of polar coordinates.

Comment: @NinadMunshi  Thank you for your comment. Would you be able to expand it into a solution?  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

$r$ is untouched by the rotation, we can work with $r=1$.

After rotation, the cone axis will go in some direction $(u, v, w)$ (a unit vector).

If suffices to express that the cone aperture is $\alpha$ by means of a scalar product:

$$u\cos\theta\sin\phi+v\sin\theta\sin\phi+w\cos\phi=\cos\alpha.$$

This gives you a $\theta,\phi$ relation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The equation is a dot product of the unit vector along the new axis of the cone and a general unit vector expressed in spherical coordinates, right?

Comment: @Confounded: right. You get a linear trigonometric equation in $\theta$ as well as in $\phi$. By expressing $(u,v,w)$ in spherical coordinates, maybe you'll get some extra simplification.